# Pandas return index name and column name function

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for pandas apply function, from which can return the tuple (index_name, column_name,value). The **value** is the entry in that row,col specified.
Something like the following function,

```
def pair(val):
  return zip(index.name,column.name,val)
```

Comment: Please give some example. Your question is very unclear of what you are asking.

Comment: @Poojan My example for this specific case is, I have an NxN shape data frame. Both the indexes and the column names are names of Cities in a country. I wanted to store the (index name,col name, weight of them) in a tuple format and push it on to a list. I'm looking for some help in Pandas apply function for this

Comment: could you provide a sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list with tuples for every value of your dataframe `df`, you can try something like this:

```
my_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for col in df.columns:
        my_list.append((index, col, row[col]))
```

If you want a list with all tuples matching a single value, this function should work:

```
def findTuples(value, df):
    my_list = []

    for col in df.columns:
        # if at least one such value in column
        if df[df[col] == value].shape[0] != 0:
            my_list = my_list + list(
                df[df[col] == value].apply(
                    lambda x: (x.name, col, x[col]),
                    axis=1
                )
            )
    return my_list
```